# How can I get a key from api with '-' in vueJS ? (returns NaN)

Tags: vuejs3

I want to retrieve the GB air quality index from the weatherapi (https://www.weatherapi.com/docs/#intro-aqi).

The problem is that the key to retrieve it in the api response is written as such:
`gb-defra-index`
and in my vue template, I get NaN but it should be an integer.

Here is my code:
`{{ weather.current.air_quality.gb-defra-index }}`

Is there any way I can solve this problem ? I don't have much experience in Vue as of today.

Comment: This seems more like a problem with the API response. This field is defined as an integer but it seems it returns you a NaN (Not a Number). Maybe you are passing invalid parameters?

Comment: turns out I just needed to do this:
{{ weather.current.air_quality['gb-defra-index'] }}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.